# Azure Devops API: Find a Git commit by Sha1 prefix, branch name or tag name?

Tags: git, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

In a local Git installation, I can use "git show" to find a specific commit, given a SHA1 hash prefix, a branch name, or a tag name.

How can I achieve the same thing with the TFS/Azure Devops API?

I have tried `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.GitHttpClientBase.[GetCommitsAsync][1]()`, but for the [`SearchCriteria.ItemVersion` and `CompareVersion`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/rest-api-for-git-getcommits-searches-backwards-whe/306115), I need to provide a `VersionType` (Branch, Tag or Commit), so unlike git-show I already have to know what kind of identifier I have. Besides, in case of "Commit", it has to be a complete SHA1 hash; a prefix won't do. Besides, I want to find exactly one commit, not a whole list.

And `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.GitHttpClientBase.GetCommitAsync()` only works with a complete SHA1 hash, not with a prefix, or a branch or tag.

Is there any API call equivalent to "git show"?

In case the version is important, it is a TFS server 2019 (Dev17.M153.5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure DevOps has a Search box on the commits page in the UI. Using that with a partial hash gives the following query criteria. It uses the [GET Commit REST method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get-commits?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511):

```
  {
    "fromCommitId": "b86c400000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "toCommitId": "b86c4fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff",
    "skip": 0,
    "maxResultCount": 25
  }
```

Or set the `searchCriteria.itemVersion.version` to the exact name and `searchCriteria.itemVersion.versionType` to `branch` or `tag` or `commit` to search for a specific commit in case you know the full name (branch, tag or full commit id).

I used the Chrome Dev Tools to capture the request. Worst case the short hash isn't unique and it will return multiple options.

For branches and tags you can also [use the `refs` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511), which has a start-with and a contains option to find the ref you're looking for.

Example:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=heads/&filterContains=replacer&api-version=6.0
```

Search for `filter=heads/` for branches and `filter=tags/` for tags, or leave the main filter empty to search both.

In theory this API can return multiple objects, since it uses `startsWith` for the `filter` and `contains` for the `filterContains`.

Comment: I haven't tried whether you can supply the versionTypeultiple times in the Request to search for more than one thing at a time.

Comment: Or whether you can leave out the `versionType` at all to search for all types.

Comment: Thank you @jessehouwing for these hints! They provide enough information so I can implement a workaround function. I'll share it here when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jesse's hints, I've come up with this implementation:

```
    public async Task<GitCommit> GetCommitClever(string id)
    {
        return await GetCommitFromTag(id)
            ?? await GetCommitFromBranch(id)
            ?? await GetCommitFromHashPrefix(id);
    }

    private async Task<GitCommit> GetCommit(string commitId)
    {
        return await m_gitClient.GetCommitAsync(commitId, m_repo.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task<GitCommit> GetCommitFromTag(string id)
    {
        var refs = await m_gitClient.GetRefsAsync(m_repo.Id, filter: "tags/" + id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (refs == null || refs.Count != 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var tag = await m_gitClient.GetAnnotatedTagAsync(m_repo.ProjectReference.Id, m_repo.Id, refs[0].ObjectId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await GetCommit(tag.TaggedObject.ObjectId);
    }

    private async Task<GitCommit> GetCommitFromBranch(string id)
    {
        var refs = await m_gitClient.GetRefsAsync(m_repo.Id, filter: "heads/" + id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (refs == null || refs.Count != 1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return await GetCommit(refs.Single().ObjectId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task<GitCommit> GetCommitFromHashPrefix(string id)
    {
        if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(id, @"\A\b[0-9a-fA-F]+\b\Z"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Branch or tag '{id}' not found.");
        }

        GitQueryCommitsCriteria crit = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria()
        {
            FromCommitId = id.PadRight(40, '0'),
            ToCommitId = id.PadRight(40, 'f')
        };
        var refs = await m_gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(m_repo.Id, crit, top: 2).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (refs == null || refs.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Commit '{id}' not found.");
        }
        if (refs.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Commit id '{id}' not unique.");
        }

        return await GetCommit(refs.Single().CommitId).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    // Using these private members:
    private GitHttpClient m_gitClient;
    private GitRepository m_repo;
```

There's room for improvement; e.g. if you have a tag "foobar" and a branch "foo", then getting a commit by id "foo" will return the tag instead of the better-matching branch. But I only need limited cleverness, so this will do.